# Open a result of `locate` with `vi`

Tags: vi, locate

I'd like to get the nth (3rd) result of `locate`, and then open it to `vi`.

```
$ locate 
/private/etc/my.cnf
/private/etc/my.cnf.bak_
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64/my.cnf 
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a pattern for `locate`; say "my.cnf":

```
vi $( locate my.cnf | head -n3 | tail -n1 )
```

Caveat: No newlines in the filenames, please. :)